# Angiular 5 & MatAutocomplete - onSelectionChangei s not always fired

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use MatAutocomplete with Angular 5, I implemented it exactly as they mentioned in material documentation, based on material documentation , I 
can use (onSelectionChange) to know when an option becomes selected, the problem is that I am not able to find a way to know when the option becomes unselected. 
when the user clears the search control for example, there is no event fired to update the model,  any help please.

here is a sample of my code

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
  <input matInput placeholder="Select a item" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="autoCompleteCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"  ngDefaultControl  [displayWith]="getDisplayFn()" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async" [value]="item" (onSelectionChange)="selectionChange(item)">
      {{ item.name }}   
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

typescript Code

```
selectedItem: any();

public getDisplayFn() {
    return (val) => this.display(val);
}
public display(item: Item): string {
    if (item) {
      return item.name;
    }
}
public selectionChange(item) {
//this is fired when an option becomes selected , 
//I need a way to clear selecedItem if the user clear the control
 this.selecedItem = item;
}
```

Comment: You defined FormControl in template `[formControl]="autoCompleteCtrl"` so you can track value's changes through it via `valueChanges` https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Comment: I think using valueChange to tack the changes on the control is an workaroud , I hope if there is a solution provided by angular material team to achieve what I want ,